# Web Application using hybrid between MySQL and Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I need to write a web application, which works only with MySQL database, but all actual data lies within an Oracle. So now i'm looking for some way to syncronize partially or use some automated tools to do that. Or just for a best practice for that case. To be clear, there's no way to use Oracle directly from web applications due to security policies. Any advices?

Comment: What language is your web application being developed in?

Comment: Having a single "source of truth" for the data is generally a good idea.  Maybe you can wrap a web service around the Oracle data and the application can integrate to that service instead of to the database directly?  Otherwise I guess you'd need to replicate the Oracle data to the MySQL database, which isn't going to be ideal by any means.  (It seems counterproductive and, well, *terribly silly* to have a security policy which dictates that applications can't access data.)

Comment: @David: perfect security can only be ensured if applications cannot access data, users cannot access applications, applications cannot be run on computers, and computers cannot access electrical power.

Comment: A thought occurs... If the security policy is in place in order to protect the data, then wouldn't replicating the data to a less secure location *completely violate that policy*?  If the application isn't allowed to access the data, don't try to undermine that fact.  What you're doing is the software equivalent of propping the access-controlled door open so people can get in even if they don't have their key card.  It "works", but it's not a good idea.

Comment: The thing is, company that i work for, has a huge database that lies only within their local network and they don't want to "open" it, yet they now need a web application for their customers. For a language i will most likely chose PHP and Yii framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **tungsten replicator** http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/ or also there is option of Data Integration / ETL tools like **talend** https://www.talend.com/resource/etl.html.